# Как правильно подключтться к бд postgres golang?

Tags: golang

Учу го, хочу просто добавить запись в бд. Подключаюсь к ней

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password=secret dbname=postgres sslmode=disable")
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

и получаю ошибку `"message": "Internal Server Error"`

Данные подключения правильные, вот конфиг докера

```
postgres:
  image: postgres
  hostname: postgres
  environment:
    POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
    PGDATA: /data/postgres
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  networks:
    - go
  restart: unless-stopped
```

Подключение к бд через GoLand работает отлично, а вот тут что то никак(

Comment: Если база расположена в отдельном контейнере postgres, значит надо и указывать адрес этого контейнера postgres, а не localhost

Comment: Да я указывал вроде)

Comment: Ну сейчас в вашем sql.Open очевидно написан localhost